# Salesforce IE 9 compatibility?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser

Are there any issues between Salesforce & Internet Explorer 9? I am not able to view/download some files in IE 9..

Comment: Please try to use tags related to your question, this will help you attract people with the right knowledge to your question! :)

Answer (score 1):

In general SFDC is [compatible with IE9](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=getstart_browser_overview.htm&language=en). Maybe the compatibility view is enabled. In order to be compliant with the salesforce IE9 recommendation you should configure your browser as described [there](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=getstart_browser_ie.htm&language=en_US#getstart_browser_ie).